# Model of table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, tikz-styles

I'm interested with this table of contents

In this question there is the answer but as i'm not good in latex i don't know how to make a tex files wich works

[Text alignment issue in custom Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96265/text-alignment-issue-in-custom-table-of-contents?rq=1)

please help me

Thank you

[image]

Comment: The code to make that TOC is directly below the picture in the link you gave.

Comment: @AML i want the code of the answer it is not complete and i don't know what i must added

Answer (score 0):

The following code combines the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96295/36296 with the document from the question:

```
\documentclass{book}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{DejaVuSansCondensed}
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem}
\RequirePackage[
  left=2.25in,
  right=0.75in,
  top=1.25in,
  bottom=1.25in,
  marginparwidth=1.75in,
  marginparsep=.25in,
  asymmetric]{geometry}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set default font

%%% Table of Contents ----------------------------------------------------------
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % Show only Chapters and Sections

%%% Change font/color/layout of TOC (with package etoc.)
% \RequirePackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoc}

% these margins will used additionally to the page margins
% set-up by package geometry
\newlength{\tocleftmargin}
\setlength{\tocleftmargin}{3.5cm}
\newlength{\tocrightmargin}
\setlength{\tocrightmargin}{1cm}

\makeatletter % for using \@chapapp of class book

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
{\parindent0pt
 \leftskip\tocleftmargin
 \rightskip\the\tocrightmargin plus 1fil
 \parfillskip0pt
 \color{cyan}}
{\addvspace{3mm}\leavevmode\bfseries\LARGE\upshape}
{\llap{\@chapapp\hspace{.5em}\etocnumber\hspace{.75cm}}\etocname
 \hfill\makebox[-\tocrightmargin][l]{\makebox[0pt]{\etocpage}}\par}
{}

\etocsetstyle{section}
{}
{\addvspace{3mm}\leavevmode\mdseries\large\itshape}
{\llap{\etocnumber\hspace{.75cm}}\etocname
 \hfill\makebox[-\tocrightmargin][l]{\makebox[0pt]{\etocpage}}\par}
{}

\makeatother

\titlecontents{section}[5.3em]
{\color{cyan}\large\itshape\addvspace{3mm}}
{\contentslabel{0em}\hspace{3.2em}}
{}
{\hspace{3em}\contentspage}
[\addvspace{0mm}]

%%% Chapter Header ----------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\scshape}
  {}{0pt}
  {\thispagestyle{empty}    % Remove page number on new chapters
  %\setcounter{definition}{0}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,-1) rectangle
          (25cm,3cm);
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,-24) rectangle
          (25cm,-25cm);
        \ifttl@label% <---------------------- Added condition on \ifttl@label
          \node[anchor=west,xshift=.21\paperwidth,yshift=-.01\paperheight,rectangle]
              {\color{white}\LARGE \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp} \Huge\thechapter};
        \fi% <------------------------------- end condition on \ifttl@label
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}\endgraf
  \vskip-.7cm
  \color{cyan}\Huge\raggedright\leftskip-1cm
   \noindent\MakeUppercase{#1}\endgraf
  }
\makeatother

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}{}

\titleformat{\section}{\color{cyan}\itshape\LARGE}{\llap{\thesection} #1}{1em}{}[\titleline{\color{cyan}\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{cyan}\normalfont\large}{\; #1}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Turing Machines}
    \section{The Turing Machine}
    \section{Variations of the Turing Machine}
      %\subsection{Non-deterministic Turing Machines}
    \section{The Church-Turing Thesis}
  \chapter{Decidability}
    \section{The Universal Turing Machine}

  \appendix
  \chapter{ON COMPUTABLE NUMBERS, WITH AN APPLICATION TO THE ENTSCHEIDUNGSPROBLEM}
\end{document}
```